# cannot connect to server via RDP- reboot solves the problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I have a suprising number of issues in a client environment that revolve around being unable to RDP to a system that has remote administration enabled.  In all cases a reboot resolves the issue.  Is there anything else that others are doing to resolve this?  I'd really rather not reboot an otherwise functional server.

Is there a way to reset the RDP connection via WMI?
Is there a way to test if the RDP protocol is functional (other than telnet to 3389)

EDIT:

As far as I can tell, no updates have been added.  It seems to just die without cause.

Comment: We had this happen a little while ago. I suspect a Windows update broke it, another round of Windows updates a few months later fixed it. I never bothered to figure out which update it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our experience this is due to a bug in Windows Server 2003 that causes issues with the remote desktop service.  From what we can tell the issues start when selecting the option to apply patches and restart.  Our mitigation is to apply patches and don't allow the process to shut down your box, then restart it manually.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  I can try to correlate RDP issue with patch installs - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can often be caused by services being started in the wrong order following an update. Sometimes starting the terminal services service will fix it but other times there are too many other services which also failed and a reboot is required.